# Commutativity in iterated Limits (Proof)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm basing this proof in the Calculus book by Apostol, if you see a error, please notify me.
If $\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)}f(x,y)=L$ and exist the two unidimensional limits $\lim_{x \to a}f(x,y)=f(a,y)$ and $\lim_{y \to b}f(x,y)=f(x,b)$ then: 
$$\lim_{x \to a}[\lim_{y \to b}f(x,y)]=\lim_{y \to b}[\lim_{x \to a}f(x,y)]=L$$
$\textbf{Proof:}$ We have: 
 $$\lim_{||(x,y)-(a,b)|| \to 0}||f(x,y)-L||=0$$ $$\lim_{||x-a|| \to 0}||f(x,y)-f(a,y)||=0$$ and $$\lim_{||y-b|| \to 0}||f(x,y)-f(x,b)||=0$$ If $\lim_{x \to a}[\lim_{y \to b}f(x,y)]=L$ is true then:
$$\lim_{||x-a|| \to 0}||f(x,b)-L||=0$$. Operating:
$$||f(x,b)-L||=||f(x,b)-L+(f(x,y)-f(x,y))||$$ 
$$=||(f(x,b)-f(x,y))+(f(x,y)-L)||$$
$$\leq||(f(x,b)-f(x,y))||+||f(x,y)-L||$$
$$\leq||-f(x,b)+f(x,y)||+||f(x,y)-L||$$
As $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\to 0$ for hypothesis, then $||x-a|| \to 0$ and $||y-b|| \to 0$ so: $$||f(x,b)-L|| \leq 0+0 $$ $$||f(x,b)-L|| \leq 0 $$
Proof of this part is well ?. If so, I know that the other side is the same. Thanks.